# Qualify a column within MONTHNAME

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I've come across a little problem that I can't seem to get my head around.

I'm searching my database for the total amount of comments a user has got over a month and then plotting in a graph.

The problem i'm having is when using `MONTHNAME` with in my SQL statement if I use

```
$this->db->select('MONTHNAME(`created_on`), COUNT(`comment.id`)');
```

I get that `created_on` field is ambiguous if I try and qualify it with the table name in front of the column

```
public function getTotalCommentsPerMonth() {

    $this->db->select('MONTHNAME(`photo_comment.created_on`), COUNT(`comment.id`)');
    $this->db->from('photo_comment');        
    $this->db->join('photo', 'photo.id = photo_comment.photo_id');
    $this->db->where('photo.userId', $this->auth->userid());
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

I get `Unknown column 'photo_comment.created_on' in 'field list'` Are you not able to qualify a column when using `MONTHNAME`?

Thanks for your help

UPDATE: Overview of `photo_comment` and photo tables

```
## photo_comment
comment_id
photo_id
user_id
created_on
comment

## photo
id
title
file_name
upload_path
userId
description
created_on
```

Comment: can you provide an overview strcuture of photo_comment and photo table.

Comment: just done it, hope it helps.

Comment: seems strange , you are doing all correct. BTW what is **`comment.id** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding backticks in your query you need to set it FALSE for active record's `select()` function,it will restrict active record to add backticks ,also you are using `COUNT(comment.id)` and in your query there is no table named as `comment` i guess you need to count the id from `photo_comment`,i have used short aliases for the tables so it will be more readable form

```
public function getTotalCommentsPerMonth() {

    $this->db->select('MONTHNAME(pc.`created_on`) AS `month_name`, 
                      COUNT(pc.`comment_id`)  AS `comment_count`',FALSE);
    $this->db->from('photo_comment pc');        
    $this->db->join('photo p', 'p.id = pc.photo_id');
    $this->db->where('p.userId', $this->auth->userid());
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

> Note: Using [**Aggregate Fucntions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) without grouping them will
>   result in a single row ,if you need the comment count for all photos
>   of user you should group by them pc.photo_id in active record you can
>   do so

```
public function getTotalCommentsPerMonth() {

    $this->db->select('MONTHNAME(pc.`created_on`) AS `month_name`, 
                      COUNT(pc.`comment_id`)  AS `comment_count`',FALSE);
    $this->db->from('photo_comment pc');        
    $this->db->join('photo p', 'p.id = pc.photo_id');
    $this->db->where('p.userId', $this->auth->userid());
    $this->db->group_by("pc.photo_id");
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem. Thanks